# What would be the 3NF of this relation?

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

```
R(ABCDE)

AB->CDE
A->C
D->E
```

Solve:

**1NF**
We presume that this is already in 1NF.

**2NF**
`AB` is the candidate key here. `A->C` is the violation.

So, we decompose them like the following:

R1 = `(AC)` + `(AB)` = `(ABC)`

R2 = R - `(AC)` + `(AB)` = `(BDE)` + `(AB)` = `(ABDE)`

**3NF**

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third normal form of your relational schema is the following:

```
R1 (A B D)    
R2 (A C)    
R3 (D E)
```

You can verify it by finding a canonical cover of the set of dependencies, which is:

```
A B → D
A → C
D → E
```

Comment: A relation is in 2NF if any non-prime attribute does not depend on any proper subset of any candidate key. Since the candidate key is only AB, the non-prime attributes are C, D, and E, and the only dependency that violates the second normal form is A->C, as you have correctly found. So, yes, the second normal form is correct, since both decompositions (ABC) and (ABDE) do not violate this form.